# Fitting mixture distributions and probability estimation

Tags: mixture-distribution

I am working on continuous data set with ranges 0-1. I need to group them using mixed models (based on prior clinical/biological basis). From this model, I need to get the p-value for a value (say 0.52) to be in the dist1(red), dist2(blue) or dist3(green). What stat methods, packages would you recommend?

I fitted the distributions using [mixtools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixtools/index.html) by defining the number of distributions, what is the state of the art method to derive this in an unsupervised way?

[image: Fitted model]

Comment: I do not know about the "state-of-the-art" (which is not necessarily widey tested) but the standard way is to use an information criterion (eg. AIC) and/or bootstrap your sample to get some confidence limits about your final estimate $k$. In addition, are you use that a KDE won't do a better job? Why enforce a parametric model in this case?

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be a bit late, but in case it helps anyone, here it goes:

An important aspect is of the mixtool package is that each input data point is actually assigned a posterior probability of belonging to one of the components that you have selected a priory (in your case 3, according to your graph). We can retrieve the data by using the following code:

```
yourdata <- as.data.frame(cbind(x = mixmdl$x, mixmdl$posterior))
head(post.df, 10)  # Retrieve first 10 rows
```

And you will see the probabilities of each data point to belong to the first, second or third distribution.

An example of the probabilities for each data point in a 2 distribution to belong to the first or second distribution:

```
##     x          comp.1         comp.2
## 1  79 0.0001030875283 0.999896912472
## 2  54 0.9999093397312 0.000090660269
## 3  74 0.0041357268361 0.995864273164
## 4  62 0.9673819082244 0.032618091776
## 5  85 0.0000012235720 0.999998776428
## 6  55 0.9998100114503 0.000189988550
## 7  88 0.0000001333596 0.999999866640
## 8  85 0.0000012235720 0.999998776428
## 9  51 0.9999901530788 0.000009846921
## 10 85 0.0000012235720 0.999998776428
```

Data extracted from 
http://tinyheero.github.io/2015/10/13/mixture-model.html)
You might find the link very useful